# UDP socket server/client on different machine won't communicate

Tags: udp, client-server

these code are from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/udp-server-client-implementation-c/. it runs well when run server and client on same machine.
but if run on two different machine in same network( they can ping each other). then server won't receive Hello from client. 
I noticed that both server and client set address INADDR_ANY. this means any machine in the local network, Am I right?
and I tried on client side specify server's ip address. server still won't get message from client.

please give me some clue.
thank you.

server.c

```
// Server side implementation of UDP client-server model 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 

#define PORT     8080 
#define MAXLINE 1024 

// Driver code 
int main() { 
    int sockfd; 
    char buffer[MAXLINE]; 
    char *hello = "Hello from server"; 
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr; 

    // Creating socket file descriptor 
    if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0 ) { 
        perror("socket creation failed"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 

    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr)); 
    memset(&cliaddr, 0, sizeof(cliaddr)); 

    // Filling server information 
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET; // IPv4 
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 

    // Bind the socket with the server address 
    if ( bind(sockfd, (const struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, 
            sizeof(servaddr)) < 0 ) 
    { 
        perror("bind failed"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 

    int len, n; 
    n = recvfrom(sockfd, (char *)buffer, MAXLINE, 
                MSG_WAITALL, ( struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, 
                &len); 
    buffer[n] = '\0'; 
    printf("Client : %s\n", buffer); 
    sendto(sockfd, (const char *)hello, strlen(hello), 
        MSG_CONFIRM, (const struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, 
            len); 
    printf("Hello message sent.\n"); 

    return 0; 
}
```

client.c

```
// Client side implementation of UDP client-server model 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 

#define PORT     8080 
#define MAXLINE 1024 

// Driver code 
int main() { 
    int sockfd; 
    char buffer[MAXLINE]; 
    char *hello = "Hello from client"; 
    struct sockaddr_in   servaddr; 

    // Creating socket file descriptor 
    if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0 ) { 
        perror("socket creation failed"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 

    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr)); 

    // Filling server information 
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 

    int n, len; 

    sendto(sockfd, (const char *)hello, strlen(hello), 
        MSG_CONFIRM, (const struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, 
            sizeof(servaddr)); 
    printf("Hello message sent.\n"); 

    n = recvfrom(sockfd, (char *)buffer, MAXLINE, 
                MSG_WAITALL, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, 
                &len); 
    buffer[n] = '\0'; 
    printf("Server : %s\n", buffer); 

    close(sockfd); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: see answer below

Answer (score 1):

in client.c
make following change. ( 192.168.1.1 ) is server's IP address. then they talk.

```
//servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 
 servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.1");
```